# Unicode and UTF-8 in python to generate csv file

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to write some variableas in a csv file. 
Documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) say the all input must be UTF-8 or ASCII, but I don't know how to set the encode ( I already tried .decode('utf-8'))

part of the code:

```
   def get_events():
       global SEVERITY, SEVERITY
       get_host()
          for HID,HNAME in zip(HOSTID,HOSTNAME):
              EVENT = zapi.event.get(time_from=DATE_FROM,
                            time_till=DATE_TILL,
                            output='extend',
                            source='0',
                            hostids=HID,
                            select_acknowledges='extend',

                            )
    for t in EVENT:
        TRIGGERID = t['objectid']
        TRIGGER = zapi.trigger.get(output='extend',
                                   triggerids=TRIGGERID,
                                   expandDescription='true',
                                   )
        for T in TRIGGER:
            TRIGGER_D = T['description'].encode('utf-8')
            SEVERITY = T['priority']
            if int(SEVERITY) < 3 or TRIGGER_D.decode('utf-8') == 'Zabbix agent on %s is unreachable for 8 minutes' % HNAME or TRIGGER_D.decode('utf-8') == '%s jmx is not reachable' % HNAME:
                continue
        NS = t['ns']
        HOUR = t['clock']
        if t.get('value') == "0":
            STATUS = "OK"
        elif t.get('value')== "1":
            STATUS = "PROBLEM"
        else:
            STATUS = "UNKNOWN"
        if t['acknowledged'] == "1":
            LISTA_DIC = t['acknowledges'][0]
            USER = LISTA_DIC['alias']
            MESSAGE = LISTA_DIC["message"]
        else:
            MESSAGE = ""
            USER = ""
        with open(FILE_OUT, 'wb') as FILE:
            FILE = csv.writer(FILE,delimiter=';') 
            FILE.writerow((HNAME,STATUS,HOUR,NS,TRIGGER_D, SEVERITY,MESSAGE,USER)
```

I'm get the error

```
“UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte”
```

Another thing: How add a newline in

```
FILE.writerow((HNAME,STATUS,HOUR,NS,TRIGGER_D, SEVERITY,MESSAGE,USER))
```

..MESSAGE,USER "\n")) doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can solve the problem change the encode to latin-1

```
FILE.writerow((HNAME,STATUS,HOUR,NS,TRIGGER_D.encode('latin-1'), SEVERITY,MESSAGE.encode('latin-1'),USER)
```